# For loop goes forever

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want this loop to decrement from the value I set it to from 10 to 0. Why does it keep going forever?

```
int lengthString = 10;

for (int j = lengthString; lengthString > 0; j--)
{
    cout << j;
}
```

Comment: Look at it again. Be patient. Use the force. Think.

Comment: Hahahaha! Thats the best answer yetr

Comment: Kerrek's comment is your best bet for becoming a better programmer. If you regularly get stuck on things like this and don't learn to find them yourself, you'll really be in trouble with the complicated stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change to

```
 for (int j = lengthString; j > 0; j--)
```

`lengthString` doesn't change in your loop.

Also, you might want to verify that `lengthString` is greater than 0 (in your real code) if you declare `j` as an `int`, because if `j` is *initialized* to a negative number, the loop will run "forever" (until it overflows and gets decreased to 0 again, that is).

Answer (score 2):

You're exit condition is `lengthString > 0`, and since lengthString doesn't change in you're loop you're just saying `while(10 > 0)`, which is true forever.

I believe you meant:

```
for (int j = lengthString; j > 0; j--)
```

Answer (score 2):

for (int j = lengthString; j >= 0; j--)

Comment: His question implies output of 10 to 0, so I indicate >= instead of >.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop decrements j, and checks if lengthString is > 0.

```
int lengthString = 10;

for (int j = lengthString; j > 0; j--)
{
    cout << j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only decrementing j, but loop condition doesn't use j

Answer (score 0):

It should be j that you are checking in your greater than, not lengthstring.

```
for (int j = lengthString; j > 0; j--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
for (int lengthString = 10, *j = &lengthString; lengthString > 0; lengthString--)
{
    cout << *j;
}
```